# How to add a scroll bar in the body of the table?

Tags: html, scroll, html-table, scrollbar

This is my code:

I need to add a scroll bar in the body of the table, the header must remain constant.
The body cells are not properly fixing if I add a scroll bar.

I need to add a scroll bar in the body of the table, the header must remain constant.
The body cells are not properly fixing if I add a scroll bar.

```
<table width="600" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; border: 1px solid #AEAEAE;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <th rowspan="2">
        Title
    </th>
    <th rowspan="2">
        Title
    </th>
    <th colspan="4">
        Title
    </th>
    <th colspan="2">
        Title
    </th>


</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
        Title
    </th>
    <th>
       Title
    </th>
    <th>
        Title
    </th>
    <th>
        Title
    </th>
    <th>
        Title
    </th>
    <th>
        Title
    </th>

</tr>

        <td height="400">
            Body
        </td>
        <td>
            Body
        </td>
        <td>
            Body
        </td>
        <td>
            Body
        </td>
        <td>
            Body
        </td>
        <td>
            Body
        </td>
        <td>
            Body
        </td>
        <td>
            Body
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Indent your HTML by four spaces when you post it so that it will show up as a code block. You can select your code and hit the **{ }** button in the formatting bar to indent it.

Answer (score 3):

Just give the table's tbody element a height and a scrolling overflow.
Like this:

```
.tableClass tbody
{
     height: 300px; /* Random number I chose */
     overflow: scroll /* you can be more specific and use overflow-y */
}
```

**Edit**:
I saw your code and your not using <[tbody](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)> and <[thead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead)>. Read about them. The general idea is to wrap the table's content with one  element, and to wrap the table's headings with one  element.

Here's a working example:
http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that code is for three columns, look at my example which I posted.

Comment: @Ronnie: It doesn't matter how many columns you have. Read my edit

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions I've found met all my requirements, so I created a very lightweight jQuery plugin to do this.  It supports fixed header, footer, column spanning (colspan), resizing, and an optional number of rows to display before scrolling starts.

[jQuery.scrollTableBody (GitHub)](https://github.com/nheldman/jquery.scrollTableBody)

As long as you have a table with proper `<thead>`, `<tbody>`, and (optional) `<tfoot>`, all you need to do is this:

```
$('table').scrollTableBody();
```